# Raspberry Pi Pico COM port setting

Tags: pi-pico

I have successfully loaded the firmware onto the (new) Pico WH and printed "Hello" from the web page as directed on Raspberry's "Getting Started" web page, but other than seeing (in the shell) the dialogue "*MicroPython v1.22.1 on 2024-01-05;...*  " I cannot communicate further with the board; ie;- I cannot programme the on-board led to flash or the blink programme to work.

Thonny is reporting that it can see the Micropython (Raspberry Pi Pico) board CDC @COM 11, but my computer file manager does not identify any COM11 port in use (only immediately after the initialisation routine - then it disappears). I an running Win10 (64 bit OS).
For other devices that I have, the USB ports work fine -  including a Raspberry Pi 4 and an Arduino board, I have followed all advice I have found on the web to no avail.

Comment: Why not run Thonny on your Pi4 and connect the Pico to that?

Comment: Thank you, I've had the same thought and as you've suggested it, will probably do it, would still be nice to know what the problem is though.

Comment: This appears to be a Windows problem.

Comment: Update from my previous query, my computer establishes comms through COM11 (serial device) and it responds to the "hello world" micro code. But that's it! It will not respond to coding for the led to light or to flash (that's all I've tried) I can see the dialogue Micro python (Raspberry Pi Pico) Board CDC@COM11 on the bottom right in Thonny

Comment: Are you running a serial comms program; e.g. `minicom`??

Comment: I don't understand, I'm not running any other programme

Comment: I'm running this on Win10 platform